# Find values in nested array using lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

I am trying to retrieve values back in a nested array but my function is returning back everything. I would like to just back the 'carTime' values in my array.

What my array is returning.

```
[
  {
    "carId": "13122",
    "carInstances": [
      {
        "carInstanceId": "472",
        "carTime": "2020-09-23T21:45:00.000+0000",
        "state": "COMPLETE",
      }
    ],
    "isPaused": false,
  },
  {
    "carId": "1312",
    "carInstances": [
      {
        "carInstanceId": "47209",
        "carTime": "2020-09-23T21:45:00.000+0000",
        "state": "COMPLETE",
      }
    ],
    "isPaused": false,
  },
]
```

Lodash:

```
const result = [
  {
    "carId": "13122656",
    "carInstances": [
      {
        "carInstanceId": "47209",
        "carTime": "2020-09-23T21:45:00.000+0000",
        "state": "COMPLETE",
      }
    ],
    "isPaused": false,
  },
  {
    "carId": "1312",
    "carInstances": [
      {
        "carInstanceId": "4720",
        "carTime": "2020-09-23T21:45:00.000+0000",
        "state": "COMPLETE",
      }
    ],
    "isPaused": false,
  },
]

const findCategoryById = (sections) => {
        const jobInstance = _.forEach(sections, (section) => {
          return section.carInstances.carTime;
        });
        return jobInstance;
      };
      findCategoryById(result)
```

Desired Output:

```
2020-09-23T21:45:00.000+0000,
2020-09-23T21:45:00.000+0000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need lodash for solving this problem. A small JS function will do with the use of reduce and map. With lodash you could do:
`_(result).flatMap('carInstances').flatMap("carTime")).values()`

```js
const result = [
  {
    "carId": "13122656-169f-45fa-be47-26c9d23dcb7b",
    "carInstances": [
      {
        "carInstanceId": "47209558-f9e1-4f81-a600-5da6ce238a6e",
        "carTime": "2020-09-23T21:45:00.000+0000",
        "state": "COMPLETE",
      }
    ],
    "isPaused": false,
  },
  {
    "carId": "13122656-169f-45fa-be47-26c9d23dcb7b",
    "carInstances": [
      {
        "carInstanceId": "47209558-f9e1-4f81-a600-5da6ce238a6e",
        "carTime": "2020-09-23T21:45:00.000+0000",
        "state": "COMPLETE",
      }
    ],
    "isPaused": false,
  },
];

const listCarTime = (res) => {
  return res.reduce((acc, car) => {
    acc.push(...car.carInstances.map((instance) => instance.carTime));
    return acc;  
  }, []);
}

console.log("lodash", _(result).flatMap('carInstances').flatMap("carTime").values())


console.log("vanilla", listCarTime(result));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It would be helpful to explain to OP "I would like to just back the 'carTime'" is done via the `.map(i => i.carTime)` part of your answer.